# Redirect naked domain to www with SSL in cloudfront/route 53

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, 301-redirect, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup two buckets on s3 one for my actual angular 2 app: www.example.com and one for redirecting example.com to www.example.com. I have also created two distributions in cloud front and added a custom certificate from amazon. Now I have the following behaviour:

1. www.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com -- OK
2. example.com redirects to https://www.example.com -- OK
3. https://example.com -- Error (This site can’t be reached)

Comment: Provide the true names without useless and unhelpful obfuscation.

Comment: Please let me know which part of the question is unclear? I found a similar issue here: https://serverfault.com/questions/883869/redirect-naked-domain-to-www-in-cloudfront-route-53#

Comment: @alizoli These issues are often solvable by letting us take a look at the domain and SSL cert. As such, please replace `example.com` with the actual domain.

Comment: What is not clear? Your app is not www.example.com so provide the true info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, this would be much easier to resolve if you provided the domain, so we can view the certificate.

As best I can gather form the information provided:

**#3** is most likely occurring because you only have a SSL certificate for www.example.com. Browsing directly to `https://example.com` MUST present the user with a valid certificate for `example.com` or `*.example.com`. The redirect cannot occur because the browser denies the TCP connection when it receives an invalid certificate for `https://example.com`, before the redirect is even attempted. You should be able to fix this by getting [a wildcard SSL certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html#wildcard) for `*.example.com`

**#2** is probably stemming from **#3**, however I cannot verify this without actually investigating the domain/certificate. The fact that it's safari-specific makes me believe Safari may handle a redirect from `http` to a subdomain over `https` differently than Firefox/Chrome. I am not well-versed in Safari, but Chrome or Firefox would give you more appropriate information as to what went wrong by using the Network tab in **Developer Tools**. [A similar toolset exists for Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/). Try using this toolset to identify the [HTTP response code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) being returned in Safari.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to fix this. I had a wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.com but I did not add the bare domain example.com to the certificate. The issue resolved by adding a certificate for *.example.com and
 example.com to the redirect cloudfront distribution.